# What type of variable in Java can hold an IP address-like number with multiple decimals?

Tags: java

This is probably the simplest question ever asked, but if I have a running number like 23.928.4934.30, which variable should house that?

Comment: Why is there a c++ tag on this question?

Comment: 928, 4934 seem strange as parts of an IP address-like number...

Comment: That "IP Address" reminds me of this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Z70BmmSkMY

Comment: I don't think it's an ip, just a set of numbers separated by `.` Kinda like version or build numbers as well.

Comment: `23.928.4934.30` doesn't look like an IP address. If you really mean IP address however, then (1) those are not "decimals" (2) `String` will do.

Comment: c++ because I figured the same logic applied. It is not an IP Address, like Andrei said. Hence the '-like' appended to it. Thanks for the answers though, guys!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `String`. If you need special logic related to it, it might be a good idea to create your own class.

Answer (score 2):

Because the question is "IP address-like" and not just for storing IP addresses, I'm going to recommend the following

Create your own class that has a List attribute. You can override toString to put dots between the numbers in the list. If for example you have numbers 123, 123, 123 and 123 in your list, your class can print them out like 123.123.123.123.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you actually have a need to access different parts of it individually, just keep it in a `String` and use [org.apache.commons.validator.routines.InetAddressValidator](http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/InetAddressValidator.html)
 to check them.

Answer (score 1):

String is the object I would use. If I want to process/parse the address (like getting the 1st octet) I would use regex for it.

Answer (score 1):

InetAddress

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html

Comment: That's too restrictive. Numbers over 255 should likely be allowed in case of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

If you do need to access specific parts of it an `int` or a `long` may be useful too: things like 192.168.2/24 are probably easier to work with in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with it directly in some sort of numerical way, you could consider a `long[]`